How to Create Text with Gradient and Emboss Effect in CSS
I am seeking to create a visual effect for text using CSS that incorporates both a gradient and embossing. I've attached an image to show the effect I'm aiming for.
Example Photo:

Here’s the background style I’m working with:
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #3e296a 0%, #6d37ac 33%, #6d37ac 72%, #10dbac 100%);

And Figma effects:


I’ve done this:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gradient Text with Emboss Effect</title>
    <style>
        .gradient-text {
            font-size: 100px;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, #3e296a, #6d37ac, #10dbac);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            color: transparent;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0px 4px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gradient-text">Decor</div>
</body>
</html>




Have you researched how to create drop shadows and inner shadows in CSS? Generally more research effort is expected before asking a question on Stack Overflow.

@Sean Thank you for your answer! I know how to make shadows in CSS. But I can't make a shadow with a color gradient. I tried to use text-shadow and box-shadow, but it didn't work. I want to make text with a color gradient and an emboss effect. The text should look 3D.

Please edit your question to show what you tried. A [mcve] using a Stack Snippet is a great way to show prior effort.

Here is something quite close with background-clip , text-shadow, -webkit-text-stroke and filter, that may inspire you. (An image or SVG could do the job too, btw)


* { box-sizing:border-box; margin:0 }
h1 {
  font-family: 'adlam display';
  font-size: clamp(20px, 25vw, 15em);
  padding: 2rem ;
  text-align: center;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #482b79, #6C36AB, #22bbab);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0.001em 0.05em .01em #0004;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.01em #00000015;
  filter: brightness(120%)
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ADLaM+Display" media="all">
<h1>Decor</h1>




Thanks a lot for the response, that really helped!

Can be done using background-clip and text-shadow


h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Garamond';
    font-size: 160px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(119deg, #B37951 7.35%, #F1CEA8 37.25%, #CB9064 72.02%, #875635 94.44%);
    /* background-clip: border-box; */
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
<h2>Decor</h2>



You can paste your color codes from figma in the background property of the CSS.

Background-image applies the color and the -webkit-background-clip clips the background and text together the text is transparent to merge with background color.


.gradient-text {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, green, blue);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
<div class="gradient-text">Decor</div>




You should copy the demo from the question down here and show your solution. I've started for you. Please revise the demo as needed. See [answer] and take the [tour].
